# Do you want a tag for each author? Or maybe each character in the story? Or each voice actor?

Tags: discussion, tags

The idea there in Chess SE already is there's no need for a tag because there's already the name in the post. I wasn't applying the rule. I was applying the idea.

> This does not help to define the question, nor does it help in the search. If (...) name is relevant to the question, it would have been used in the question body anyway; thus, being searchable.

[Did Kazuki Takahashi had any involvement with the Yu-Gi-Oh Duel Monsters Anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/65785/did-kazuki-takahashi-had-any-involvement-with-the-yu-gi-oh-duel-monsters-anime)

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71009

https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/should-we-create-tags-named-after-chess-players

Comment: Why? What benefit would it provide compared to not having it. It feels redundant

Comment: Note that we also have [tag:hayao-miyazaki] tag for questions about his works in general.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless there exists an on-topic, reasonable question that requires an answer at the level of a single *creator* rather than:

- The specific show
- The specific studio
- The specific art style
- The specific universe (thinking [Nasuverse](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Franchise/Nasuverse) as an example to reach for)